# Colocate pods in Kubernetes

Tags: performance, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, affinity

- I have a kubernetes cluster which is spread across 2 zones- zone1 and zone2.
- I have 2 applications- a web application and a database. The web application's configurations are stored in the database. Both the application as well as the database are deployed as stateful applications.
- The idea is to deploy 2 replica sets for web application (application-0 and application-1) and 2 replica for database (database-0 and database-1). application-0 points to database-0, application-1 points to database-1.
- Pod anti-affinity has been enabled. So preferably application-0 and application-1 will not be in same zone. Also database-0 and database-1 will not be in same zone.
- I want to ensure application-0 and database-0 are in the same zone. And application-1 and database-1 are in another zone. So that the performance of the web application is not compromised. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have strict separation of the workloads over the two zones - I'd suggest using [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) on a node's zone.

A similar result is possible with pod affinity but it's more complex and to get the clear split you describe. You'd need to use the requiredDuringScheduling / execution rules which are usually best avoided unless you really need them.

Comment: How would the nodeSelector work in case of stateful sets? Won't both application-0 and application-1 be placed in same zone if I put a nodeSelector condition based on zones?

Comment: StatefulSets still create pods that need to be scheduled to nodes. So nodeSelector still works since it operates at the pod level.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you used anti-affinity rules to avoid provisioning both apps in the same zone, you can use affinity to provision app-0 only in the zone where db-0 exists, technically that would mean that you could drop anti affinity from app completely as if you tell it to schedule only in the zone of db, and db is defined to spread zones with anti-affinity, you inherit the distribution from the database part.

Comment: I did not get the desired results. I executed it 2 times- First time app-0 and db-0 was on node-0 and app-1 and db-1 was on node-1. Second time app-0 and db-1 was on node-0 and app-1 and db-0 was on node-1. The desired result is what I found the first time.

Answer (score 0):

### PodAntiAffinity to spread to Zones

For your **database**

```
metadata:
  labels:
    app: db
spec:
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: app
            operator: In
            values:
            - db
        topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

For your **web-app**

```
metadata:
  labels:
    app: web-app
spec:
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: app
            operator: In
            values:
            - web-app
        topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

### PodAffinity to co-locate pods on nodes

In addition, you add `podAffinity` to your web-app (not database) to co-locate it on nodes with your database.

With `podAffinity` added for your **web-app**:

```
metadata:
  labels:
    app: web-app
spec:
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: app
            operator: In
            values:
            - web-app
        topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
    podAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: app
            operator: In
            values:
            - db
        topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

**Result**

With both `PodAntiAffinity` and `PodAffinity` you will get web-app-X co-located with db-X.

```
web-app-1     web-app-2
db-1          db-2
```

See the Kubernetes documentation has an example to [co-locate cache with app on nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#always-co-located-in-the-same-node) about `PodAffinity` and ´PodAntiAffinity`.

### Stable Network identity for StatefulSet

To address [one specific instance](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id) of a StatefulSet, create an [Headless Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) with `ClusterIP: None` for each **db replica**. This allow your web-apps to connect to a specific instance.

**Access the closest db instance**

Now your web-apps can connect to db-0 and db-1 via the headless services. Let your web-apps connect to both initially, and use the one with shortest response time - that one is most likely the one on the same node.

Comment: I did not get the desired results. I executed it 2 times- First time app-0 and db-0 was on node-0 and app-1 and db-1 was on node-1. Second time app-0 and db-1 was on node-0 and app-1 and db-0 was on node-1.
The desired result is what I found the first time.

Comment: @user3623483 an web-app will always be co-located with a db-instance with that setup. Why is it important to have the same ordinal co-located, with this setup they get the best performance as you looked for. Why is the same ordinal of web-app and db important?

Comment: In my web-app I am mentioning the connection details like that. app-0 connects to db-0 and app-1 connects to db-1. db-0 and db-1 are replicating between themselves.
Should I create a service for the DB and point to that instead? Would K8s take care of the performance on its own if I do this?

Comment: @user3623483 see my update for a possible solution, where you select the db-instance with shortest response time.

Comment: @user3623483 did my updated suggestion help? Alternatively you may look at what IP-range the IP for db-0 and db-1 are, pods on the same node should be allocated IP from the same node-range, but that solution may not be easy or stable.